# How to take SVN Dump revision wise in fedora

Tags: svn, svndump

I am new user and first time using SVN, i don't know how to take SVN dump revision wise.any one please help me.

Answer (score 1):

To dump (for example) revision 12:

```
svnadmin dump -r 12 /path/to/repository > /tmp/revision12.dump
```

note this can't access a remote repository, you need to run svnadmin on the same server your repository physically sites on.